az Cmdlet not available despite Az Module listing as being installed
so I'm following along the Microsoft Azure Guide for developing a simply Python function for Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-python?pivots=python-mode-decorators&tabs=windows%2Cbash%2Cazure-cli%2Cbrowser#configure-your-local-environment
For this, the Azure PowerShell shall be installed (or the Azure CLI): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-azps-windows?view=azps-12.1.0&tabs=windowspowershell&pivots=windows-psgallery
So I've installed the Azure Powershell via the PowerShell Gallery, as is recommended.
Now PowerShell shows me this module as installed. But the az Cmdlet is not recognized. And yes, I've restarted the Powershell instance.

I've checked, and apparently it should be installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin. But there is no Azure folder in the Microsoft SDKs folder on my machine.
Anyone had this problem too and knows a solution other than using the MSI package?

Oh, I see my mistake now. The guide distinguishes between the CLI and PowerShell when asking to create Azure resources. I somehow ignored this up until now. Thanks for being my rubber duck :D


There is a clear distinction between the Az Module, that only has PowerShell cmdlets and the az CLI. See Install Azure CLI on Windows for installation details.
